# apache flume log directory

Tags: flume, flume-ng

Just begin to learn Apache Flume. I follow the instructions on Flume official getting started website:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLUME/Getting+Started

Almost everything is fine after follow the instructions on above link. But I could not find any log file afterwards. I suppose log file is under {flume.directory}/logs. Any idea to find flume log files?

Here comes my log4j.properties:

```
flume.root.logger=INFO,LOGFILE
flume.log.dir=./logs
flume.log.file=flume.log

log4j.logger.org.apache.flume.lifecycle = INFO
log4j.logger.org.jboss = WARN
log4j.logger.org.mortbay = INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyTransceiver = WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop = INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hive = ERROR

# Define the root logger to the system property "flume.root.logger".
log4j.rootLogger=${flume.root.logger}


# Stock log4j rolling file appender
# Default log rotation configuration
log4j.appender.LOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.File=${flume.log.dir}/${flume.log.file}
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%t] (%C.%M:%L) %x - %m%n


# Warning: If you enable the following appender it will fill up your disk if you don't have a cleanup job!
# This uses the updated rolling file appender from log4j-extras that supports a reliable time-based rolling policy.
# See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/TimeBasedRollingPolicy.html
# Add "DAILY" to flume.root.logger above if you want to use this
log4j.appender.DAILY=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DAILY.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.DAILY.rollingPolicy.ActiveFileName=${flume.log.dir}/${flume.log.file}
log4j.appender.DAILY.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=${flume.log.dir}/${flume.log.file}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}
log4j.appender.DAILY.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.DAILY.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%t] (%C.%M:%L) %x - %m%n


# console
# Add "console" to flume.root.logger above if you want to use this
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d (%t) [%p - %l] %m%n
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause your configuration use a relative path :

```
flume.log.dir=./logs
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.File=${flume.log.dir}/${flume.log.file}
```

Flume use your current directory to log.
(the directory where you are when you launch flume)

You can use an absolute path for `flume.log.dir` if you want to force flume to log in that path, no matter where you launch it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `log4j.properties`, it would be in the same directory where you start your `flume-agent`, thats what `./` would do.

So, if you run from `/home` directory, it would be

`/home/logs/flume.log`

**Also,** you can use linux commands anytime to find that out,

`find / -name flume.log ##search in whole disk`

`find . -name flume.log ##search in current directory`